# Deployed a MEAN stack app to Heroku, having trouble testing locally

Tags: express, heroku, mean-stack

I've deployed a MEAN stack app to Heroku following the instructions released by Heroku here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mean-apps-restful-api. I've set the database url as an environment variable in Heroku and the Heroku deployment is working as it should, as you can see here: https://whispering-river-53899.herokuapp.com/.

My problem is that I am now unable to test locally, and I'm reluctant to clog up my git logs with untested commits. When running locally, I'm hard coding process.env.MONGO_DB in server.js to the url that would ordinarily be set by the environment variable (I remove this before committing) and run the app with "ng serve". The page loads with the nav bar and the header, but not the table contents. When I check the network tab, the query to the /api/monsters route that would normally return those results is returning a 404 error with the message "Cannot GET /api/monsters".

My code can be found here: https://github.com/allredbm/Monster-Playbook

I'm looking for the changes that need to be made to my code to allow for my database to be accessed while I'm testing locally. I plan to revert these changes back to the current state before pushing to heroku.

Comment: in my mean app/website, i use `return this.http.post<any>(location.protocol + "//" + location.host + "/api/addStock", data, options);`. which gets `http`/`https` for the protocol, and for example `www.mywebsite.co.uk` as the host, i then append the endpoint ` + "/api/addStock"`

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. The issue was that I hadn't run a build of my site locally and didn't have a /dist folder. After doing that and running on port 3000, which I set my backend to listen on, I am able to view the data properly now.